# Explanation of awk statement

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I am not able to understand this statement:

```
awk '/^\/\*/ {f=1} {print f?"":$0} /\*\/$/ {f=0}'
```

Comment: I feel the same way about "Someone left my cake out in the rain" so I share your pain. Do you have a question, though?

Answer (score 6):

It normally prints a file, only that shows empty lines whenever they are inside a block of comments like this:

```
/*

*/
```

#### Explanation

```
awk '/^\/\*/ {f=1} {print f?"":$0} /\*\/$/ {f=0}'
     ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^
        |                 |          |
        |                 |        match lines ending with */
                    print either the line or an empty line
     match lines starting with /* (\ is to escape the chars)
```

By pieces:

```
/^\/\*/ {f=1}
```

Whenever it finds a line starting with `/*`, it sets `f` variable to 1. `^` refers to `beginning of string`. In this case, `beginning of line`. This could change if `RS` was set to something different to new line.

```
/\*\/$/ {f=0}
```

Whenever it finds a line ending with `*/`, it sets `f` variable to 0. `$` refers to `end of string`. In this case, `end of line`.

```
{print f?"":$0}
```

Prints either an empty line or the current line (which is accessed with `$0`). This is equivalent to:

```
if (f == True)
   print $0
else
   print ""
```

As [Ed Morton nicely comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388363/explanation-of-awk-statement#comment35833549_23388461), it is safer to use parenthesis to avoid errors:

```
{print (f?"":$0)}
```

#### Example:

Sample file:

```
$ cat a
hello
/*aa
aaa
bbbj
*/
bye
```

Execution:

```
$ awk '/^\/\*/ {f=1} {print f?"":$0} /\*\/$/ {f=0}' a
hello




bye
```

Comment: Great answer, good explanation of how the awk command is composed.

Comment: +1 You should mention that `print f?"":$0` will produce syntax errors with some awks and `print (f?"":$0)` should be used instead. Also, is it worth mentioning that `^` and `$` mean start/end of a string, not line, and that in this context for awk they match on the start/end of a record which just happens to be a line in this case? idk... maybe too much...

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton !! Always learning from you. I edited accordingly. It is good to have `RS`, but also prevents us to use "line" when talking about records, so I sometimes don't like it :D